# Rounded corner CSS not working with table in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a table on my page that I am unable to apply rounded corners to for Firefox. I have tested on IE, Chrome, and Safari and it works fine on those browsers.

**HTML**

```
<table class="login-table">
    <tr id="header">
        <td id="logo">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    height:85px;
    width:170px;
    border-top-right-radius:14px;
    border-top-left-radius:14px;
}
```

I tried adding `-moz-border-radius-topleft:14px` and `-moz-border-radius-topright:14px` to `#logo`, but it did not change my output.

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jzdy7yz4/) which shows my issue.

Comment: Which version are you using? On Firefox 35, the outer borders are rounded and the inner top borders are not (the inner bottom are).

Comment: I was on 33.1, but am upgrading now.

Comment: @BobM I would like the inner top borders to be rounded. As they are in all other browsers, but not Firefox.

Comment: The code included in the question does not produce the problem described (and differs substantially from the fiddle). It does not even set any border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me that the `tr` element is actually keeping it's square edges, causing the issue.  If you make the `tr` itself transparent, and make sure the children don't inherit the transparent background-color, it seems to work:

```
// The first <tr>
#header { 
    background-color: transparent!important;
}

// The child of the first <tr>
#logo {
    background-color:#1c918a;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o9z695hf/

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was pretty sure the tr element was making the edge square, but did not think about making it's background transparent. Thank you for the time and insight!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to show the top rounderd by moving the CSS down to .container and adding a few changes (`height: 100%`, etc.)

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/jzdy7yz4/16/

I still see what looks like a white 1px border outside. I suppose it is some kind of spacing.